# Javascript appending style to event.target

Tags: javascript

I have a function `clickEvent(event)` and an array. I want to push the element to the array and later loop through this list to compare the elements with the elements of another array containing the same elements. The problem is that when I add a style to the element, the HTML of the element changes and is no longer the same as the element in the other list. Why is the element containing the style added to the list? I am adding the style after pushing the element, so I don't understand why this is happening.

Is there another way to add a background to the element without appending a style to said element?

```
clickEvent(event) { 
   array.push(event.target);
   event.target.style.background = 'red';
}
```

Comment: where is your HTML and button ?

Comment: Is your question “why does the element in the array have a red background”?

Comment: MTCoster yes, that is correct

Comment: What information exactly do you need to compare between the two arrays?

Comment: The html of the elements

Answer (score 2):

What you are adding to the list is only a reference to an HTML element, not the actual element itself.
What you would need to do is clone the event target and add the clone to the list instead.

For example:

```
array.push(event.target.cloneNode());
```

This will then create an entirely new copy of the element that will not get changed when the original element is changed.

Additional information about the cloneNode method can be found at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode

Comment: So I could do something like: 

let var1 = event.target;
let var2 = event.target; 

and then push var2 to the array? And that would not contain the style?

Comment: @Jonathan there's a high chance that DOM elements are treated as objects, in which case they are passed by reference, not value. This would mean that if you used `let var1 = event.target` and `let var2 = event.target`, then modify `var1`, the changes apply to `var2` as well.

Comment: I have added an edit that shows which code to use to create a copy of the element.